# Frequency compensation circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpwOGv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The diagram above is part of my constant current circuit which function as frequency compensation circuit. I was given the time constant from square wave test which is \$7.5\mathrm{ms}\$. How do I find the values of \$R\$ and \$C\$ if I want to achieve time constant of \$0.05\mathrm{ms}\$?

the linear differential equation of the circuit would be:
$$
RC\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}(E_{in}-E_{out})}{\mathrm{d}t} - (E_{in}-E_{out}) = E_{out}\cdot\frac{R}{R_c}
$$
Note: None of the voltage input or output is given.

So far I have tried letting \$E_{in}=0\$ and get the equation by integrating both sides, then do the same thing by letting \$E_{out}=0\$. So I am stuck with two exponential equations. I am lost as to where do I start with, do I just assign a value for \$E_{in}\$?

Comment: What part is constant current?

Comment: Ein is connected to another part of the circuit which has resistor that act like sensor. I have updated the diagram but the part that matters is the frequency compensation circuit (RC).

Comment: I can't see the the load and the current feedback from your constant current source. What you have depicted is a simple buffer.

Comment: the buffer is used to prevent loading of the sensor by the compensation circuit

Answer (score 0):

> the buffer is used to prevent loading of the sensor by the
>   compensation circuit

The simplest LPF is a RC, output of opamp goes through the resistor and capacitor. 
$$\tau=RC$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGZV70.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>